# How construct $\mathbb R$ algebraically ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers

We can construct $\mathbb Q$ from $\mathbb Z$ using a quotient. Topologically, $\mathbb R$ is construct as the space where all Cauchy-sequence of $\mathbb Q$ converge (and we can also construct $\mathbb R$ in a different way). But is there a way to construct algebraically $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is not "constructed" from $\Bbb Z$ using a quotient, to be pedantic.

Comment: You define $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff ad-bc=0$ and then $\mathbb Q=\mathbb Z/_\sim$. @KennyLau

Comment: Yes, and there is no quotient involved. Also, $\Bbb Q = (\Bbb Z \times (\Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}))/\sim$.

Comment: Did you mean quotient in the sense of a set quotient an equivalence relation?

Comment: @KennyLau: Yes of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can construct the reals directly from the integers by an algebraic process (it's the quotient of the ring of quasi-homomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$ by a certain equivalence relation). See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405803/constructing-the-reals-from-the-integers) and, above all, the comments and the answer.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Surb I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @Surb consider accepting his answer if you considered it helpful.